# PHP load array from file foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have this code:

```
require("class.XMLHttpRequest.php");
function hot($news){
 $url="https://localhost/search.aspx?search=".$news.""; 
 $ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
 $ajax->setRequestHeader("Cookie","Cookie: host");
 $ajax->open("GET",$url,true);
 $ajax->send(null);
 if($ajax->status==200){
  $rHeader=$ajax->getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie");
  if(substr_count($rHeader, "Present!")>0) { return true; }
 }else{ return false; }
} 

$celebrities = array('britney','gaga','carol');
$filename = 'result.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
foreach($celebrities as $celebrity)
{
    if(hot($celebrity)) { fwrite($handle, "{$celebrity}\r\n"); };
}
fclose($handle);
```

And instead of

```
$celebrities = array('britney','gaga','carol');
$filename = 'result.txt';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'a');
foreach($celebrities as $celebrity)
{
    if(hot($celebrity)) { fwrite($handle, "{$celebrity}\r\n"); };
}
fclose($handle);
```

I want to implement

```
$read_file = fopen('array.txt', 'r');
$write_file = fopen('result.txt', 'a');

while(!feof($read_file))
{
    $celebrity = fgets($read_file);
    if(hot($celebrity)) { fwrite($handle, "{$celebrity}\r\n"); }
}

fclose($write_file);
fclose($read_file);
```

now the result.txt doesnt gets written anymore, where do i go wrong?
the script should read an array from a file, process the function hot and then write each reasults in a new line in result.txt
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a single celeb per line:

```
$celebrity = trim(fgets($read_file));
```

As `fgets` will return a string *including* the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

On the line:

```
if(hot($celebrity)) { fwrite($handle, "{$celebrity}\r\n"); }
```

You use `$handle`, which is no longer defined. You want to be using `$write_file` instead:

```
if(hot($celebrity)) { fwrite($write_file, "{$celebrity}\r\n"); }
```